# How do I specify where a span will be placed in a extjs grid?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm trying to understand the code I edited.

So I created the following variable 
    var headerPlaceHolderComponent = '()';

and placed it in the function below

```
    formatTitle: function (containerWidth, containerNameTitle, aggregationTitle) {
    // one character approximates to 6 pixels. So, dividing by 5.5
    var maxCharacters = Math.ceil(containerWidth / 5.5);
    var combinedTitle = containerNameTitle + aggregationTitle;

    if (combinedTitle.length > maxCharacters) {
        var numberOfCharsToTruncate = maxCharacters - combinedTitle.length;
        aggregationTitle = aggregationTitle.replace(aggregationTitle.slice(numberOfCharsToTruncate), '...');
    }

    var formattedContainerNameTitle = '<span class="conatiner-name-title">' + containerNameTitle + '</span>';
    var formattedAggregationTitle = '(<span class="aggregation-title-style-in-grid">' + aggregationTitle + '</span>)';
    var headerPlaceHolderComponent = '(<span class="header-placeholder"></span>)';
    var formattedCombinedTitle = aggregationTitle.length > 0 ? formattedContainerNameTitle + ' ' + formattedAggregationTitle + headerPlaceHolderComponent
                                    : formattedContainerNameTitle + headerPlaceHolderComponent ;
    return formattedCombinedTitle;
},
```

Currently the Span that I created renders out in HTML within the following span.

```
<span class="x-panel-header-text x-panel-header-text-default-framed" id="ext-gen1419">
     <span id="ext-gen1525" class="header-placeholder"></span> <!--My Span -->
</span>
```

I would like my span to render within this div instead:

So my final rendered coded will look like this:

```
<div class="x-component x-box-item x-component-default" id="component-1196" role="heading">  
    <span id="ext-gen1525" class="header-placeholder"></span> <!--My Span -->
</div>
```

How can I specify where in the HTML my span will render?

Comment: Are you trying to render/generate the grid's header title using your function?

Comment: No,the header is created already

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Can you post a sketch? In Ext you almost never need to go down to HTML and if do then you usually create XTemplates to generate what you need.